# ClickOn Add User button (sign-in) window

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to click on AddUser button on windows sign-in page.

Using pywinauto, I am trying to click on the AddUser option. Is this even possible ?

Comment: Please try searching existing questions in SO. It might answer your query.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What about your research? Googling your question maybe...?